# How can I run multiple discord tokens one by one until it sends X messages in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm writing some code that send messages to X people with a token and then change to another in a list. Ex:

```
tokens = [token1, token2, token3 ... token100]
for token in tokens:
    client.run(token)
```

My doubt is basically: how can i finish the run function when X messages have been sent and then go to the next token

Comment: That sounds like spam accounts or general spam, is already a violation of Discord's ToS. I assume that no one will help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved the problem and i hope it can help everybody =]
I don't care about TOS, so here's:

```
import discord
import asyncio

conta = 0

tokens = list(map(lambda t : t.split(':')[2], open('tokens.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()))

async def main():
    while True:
        for token in tokens:
            client = discord.Client()

            @client.event
            async def on_ready():
                print(f'Logged on as {client.user.name}')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await client.close()

            try:
                client.loop.run_until_complete(await client.start(token))
            except Exception as e:
                continue

asyncio.run(main())
```